# working with the collection of objects in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

Trying to work with the collection of objects.
the collection is NOT an Eloquent one but hand made `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

if i understood it right in the case of collection of objects i'm not able to use most of methods but only those which can use callback.

so, i have collection of objects:
[image]

and here is the code ($country = 'Russia'):

```
        dump($this->countries);
        $filtered = $this->countries->filter(function ($countryObj) use($country) {
            dump($countryObj->name == $country);
            return $countryObj->name == $country;
        });
        dd($filtered);
```

i expect the `$filtered` contains only one element, the one which return `true` (in our case Russia)
but instead of it i have the same collection of 3 elements.

here is the rest of classes to be sure they are collection related

```
use App\Services\Taxes\DataSourceInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

abstract class JsonModel extends Collection implements DataSourceInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->readDataFile(env('JSON_DATA_PATH')));
    }

    protected function readDataFile(string $path): array
    {
        $disk = Storage::disk('local');

        try {
            $dataObj = json_decode($disk->get($path), false, 10, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
            return $this->loadData($dataObj);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException $e) {
            Log::error('Storage ' . $e->getMessage() . ' was not found');
        } catch (\JsonException $e) {
            Log::error('Json DataFile: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return [];
    }

    abstract protected function loadData(object $dataObject): array;
}
```

```
class JsonCountries extends JsonModel
{
    public function loadData(object $dataObject): array
    {
        $data = array_filter($dataObject->countries, function ($item){
            unset($item->states);
            return true;
        });

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post here your `JsonCountries` class? Maybe your `JsonCountries` class doesn't extend `Collection` class

Comment: @aceraven777, i have updated the post with the rest of classes. it is collection for sure at least coz i can use basic methods like `$this->countries->first()` and `dump($this->countries instanceof Collection );` is true

Comment: Can you try `dd($filtered->all());`

Comment: i tried it, it return all 3 entries

Answer (score 0):

problem was in `new static` which used inside laravel methods which return instance of collection and in fact that i dont expect array entry in my constructor.

choice between empty array and file reading fixes the problem

```
abstract class JsonModel extends Collection implements DataSourceInterface
{
    public function __construct($dataArr = [])
    {
        if(!is_array($dataArr))
           $dataArr = $this->readDataFile(env('JSON_DATA_PATH'));

        parent::__construct($dataArr);
    }
```